# ¿Cómo funciona y cómo trabajan los parámetros de una función?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo funciona y cómo trabajan los parámetros de una función?

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');

function mifuncion(t,r) {
  console.log('Sip');
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="dato1" required>
  <input type="text" id="dato2" required>
  <button onclick="mifuncion(event)">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola @Gamez. Las etiquetas que has proporcionado no son relevantes a tu pregunta. PHP no tiene nada que ver aquí y tampoco jQuery porque este es una característica **de lenguaje**, no de una librería.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno, primero tienes que saber que una "función" es un trozo de código que hacen una función o tarea especifica.

Un ejemplo básico es una calculo matemático.
Mira esta función:

```
function sumar( a, b){
    console.log(a + b)
}
```

Esta función para que pueda funcionar, necesita 2 parametos que son `a` y `b` (2 datos o variables) para que pueda funcionar

Hagamos una llamada de una función pasandole los parametos:

```
sumar( 1, 2)
```

Esto lo que hará es sumar 1 + 2 y te mostrara en consola el resultado

Veamos otro ejemplo:
Yo voy a hacer una función que me repita un codigo según las veces que yo le pase por parametros a la función

```
function repetir( repeticiones ){
    for ( var i = 1; i <= repeticiones; i++){
        console.log('repeticion numero' + i)
    }
}
```

llamamos la funcion

```
repetir(4) // repetira el codigo 4 veces
repetir(1000) // repetira el codigo mil veces
```

Comment: Y como seria llamadas de funciones dentro de otra función

Comment: Bueno si ya entendiste esta parte, formula otra pregunta, porq aqui no te lo puedo explicar muy detallado.

Comment: @Gamez. ¿Esta respuesta responde a tu juicio **cómo funcionan los parámetros** o responde a **para qué sirven**? En ese caso, utiliza bien las palabras por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Los parámetros en una función so simplemente valores que pasas para ser procesados o ser parte de un proceso. Los parámetros de una función pasan a ser en realidad variables locales. De esta manera, lo siguiente:

```
function (name, lastname) { }
```

Pasa a ser:

```
function () {
  var name, lastname;
}
```

Una función, en JavaScript acepta el paso de valores por valor; es decir, no existe paso por referencia. Si pasas una variable a una función, en realidad se hace una "copia" de dicha variable:

```js
let name = 'John';

changeName(name, 'Leslie');
console.log(name);

function changeName (name, newVal) {
  name = newVal;
}
```

Sin embargo, hay ciertos escenarios que son bastante interesantes, ya que dan la impresión que se están haciendo cambios al parámetro como si este hubiese sido pasado como referencia:

```js
let person = {
  name: 'John'
};

changeName(person, 'Leslie');
console.log(person.name);

function changeName(obj, newVal) {
  obj.name = newVal;
}
```

Entonces, ¿qué está pasando aquí? Lo que pasa es simplemente lo siguiente:

> Cuando pasas objetos en JavaScript, estos se pasan por valor, pero este valor es realmente una "referencia". Esto es llamado [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) y es una idea implementada en varios lenguajes como Python y Java. Si le cambias la **referencia** al objeto, los cambios no son persistidos fuera de la función, peros si cambias **propiedades** del objeto, estos cambios sí son persistidos.

```js
let person = {
  name: 'John'
};

changeReference(person);
console.log(person.name);
changeName(person, 'Leslie');
console.log(person.name);

function changeReference (obj) {
  obj = {
    name: 'Leslie'
  };
}

function changeName(obj, newVal) {
  obj.name = newVal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Los parámetros de una función sirven tanto para enviar como para recibir valores para que sean procesados. Por ejemplo si tenes una función que tiene como parámetros `$varA` y `$varB` y dentro de la función los sumas, y el retorno es el total, cuando invoques la función en otro ámbito de la aplicación el resultado va a variar dependiendo los valores que le pases. Estos pueden ser tanto variables como valores explícitos.

En el ejemplo que citas no creo que funcione con normalidad ya que al crear una función con parámetros cuando la invocas debes pasar la misma cantidad de parámetros y con valores del mismo tipo.

Answer (score 1):

`var form` es referente a el nombre de la variable en este caso es form. La instrucción `document.getElementById('form')` obtiene el id de algun elemento donde quieras mostrar la informacion que hace la función; en este caso tu id se llama form.

```
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
```

La funcion nombrada como `mifuncion` define que recibe dos parámetros, los cuales pueden contener numeros o texto dependiendo de las necesidades del usuario. La instrucción `console.log` indica que el resultado de la función será mostrado en la consola del navegador. Para verlo visualizado pulsa `f12`, selecciona la opción consola y aparecerá el resultado.

```
function mifuncion(t,r) {
  console.log('Sip');
}
```

Al hacer click en el botón es cuando mandas llamar a la función `mifuncion`:

```
<button onclick="mifuncion(event)">Enviar</button>
```